# How can I stop Steam from loading when I start my computer?

Tags: steam

Every time I boot into OSX or Windows, Steam automatically starts.

Is there a way to stop Steam starting whenever I boot up my computer?

Comment: Have you tried unchecking "Run Steam when my computer starts." under the Interface tab in your Steam Preferences?

Comment: This is confusing, do you want Steam to not download stuff automatically or to not start on every boot?

Comment: @Krazer I didn't find this option before Kalina's answer =)

Comment: @kotekzot Not start on every boot

Comment: for me setting steam prefs didn't help so issue `open /Users/yourname/Library/LaunchAgents ` command and remove valve related plist file.

Comment: FOUND IT: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/stop-apps-launching-mac/ I would have posted a correct answer, but I don't have enough points. (none of the other answers will work on MacOS)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

## This can be done from within the Steam client

There is an option within Steam that toggles whether or not Steam starts with your computer. To change it, open up the main Steam window and select 'Preferences' from the 'Steam' menu, followed by selecting the 'Interface' tab, which brings up the following screen;

[image]

Simply uncheck 'Run Steam when my computer starts' to prevent Steam from starting with your computer. (Obviously if you wanted to Steam to start with your PC, you'd check this box instead of unchecking it!)

## macOS

If, on macOS, this doesn't work for you, check for Steam in "System Preferences" > "Users & Groups" > [Your user] > "Login Items", and remove it via the '-' sign.

[image: macOS login items]

Comment: Does not work for OSX sadly. PS: Greetings from the vault! :P

Comment: Does not work in macOS

Comment: If unchecking the setting in Steam doesn't work for you on macOS you should check for Steam in "System Preferences" > "Users & Groups" > [Your user] > "Login Items".

Comment: @EvilOatmeal I added this suggestion as an edit.

Comment: learned something about macos

Answer (score 12):

An alternative solution on Windows (starting from 8) is to open task manager and disable Steam Client Bootstrapper from the Start-up tab.

[image: Task Manager, Start-up, Steam Client Bootstrapper, Dropdown menu, Disable]

**Note:** This is an override switch to Steam's setting. You cannot re-enable it from Steam settings after disabling it here.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 7 click the Start menu and type `msconfig` in the Search box. In the System Configuration program that opens, click the Startup tab, and then uncheck Steam. This does pretty much same thing as the Windows 8 tip.

Comment: The usage of pictures are great. but +1 anyway

Answer (score 4):

OSX = open steam then next to apple icon in top left corner
steam > preferences > interface
then uncheck - 'run steam when my computer starts'

Comment: This seems like the right answer but Steam is starting at login on mine and this box is not checked.  I've also confirmed it's not set to "Open at Login" in the dock.  I'm going to try checking this box, clicking OK, and then unchecking it again to see if that helps.

Comment: @KCBaltz Can confirm... wtf

Comment: TrudleR's comment brought me back here.  I don't have this problem with Steam anymore, so checking and unchecking must have fixed it.

Comment: Does not work in macOS

Answer (score 4):

For Mac users:

1. Go to the  Apple menu and choose “System Preferences”, then go to “Users & Groups”
2. Select the user that is active in OS X, then choose the “Login Items” tab
3. Select “Steam” from this list and then hit the Delete key on the keyboard to remove steam from the automatic launch on login list
4. Close out of System Preferences

Comment: Hello darkness my old friend