# How do I enable Steam at system start?

Tags: steam

A little bit ago, I was stupid and deleted my Windows (7) registry key for auto starting Steam on login. I foolishly had deleted it, not disabled. Now I'd like it to auto start on login, but I have no way of setting it up to do so.

Any thoughts? Should I attempt to reinstall Steam or what?

Comment: Related (doing the opposite): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102996/how-can-i-stop-steam-from-loading-when-i-start-my-computer

Answer (score 5):

In the Steam menu go to `Steam -> Settings -> Interface` and check `Run Steam when my computer starts`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to auto-login, You have to make sure steam remembers your login information as well.  `Steam > settings > Account` tab. Un-check `Don't save account credentials on this computer`.

Also make sure to use the changes kotezot provided.